# PHP Curl Posting @ Sign Returning False

Tags: php, post, curl

I got this test code.

File name: test.php

```
<?php
$array = array(
            'host' => "@"
        );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/post.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
?>
```

and this, post.php

```
<?php
  var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Whenever I use "@" as a value, i get a false result like this,

```
bool(false)
```

but when I use " @" or "any@" like that, I get this result

```
array(1) { ["host"]=> string(2) " @" }
```

any explanations and solutions about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@` prefix is used to specify the file path (uploading the file).

You could disable `@` prefix by setting the `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` (need php version >= 5.5) option to `TRUE`.

Or you could just use a query string instead of an array.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "host=@");
```

Comment: I was about to ask what if multiple hosts, and coming from an array. so I did

$array = array('host1' => '@','host2' => '@');
$post = http_build_query($array);
$post = str_replace("amp;", "", $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

Thank you so much for the explanation and for the idea @xdazz!